# How to change field type in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a schema:

```
schema "editables" do
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string

    timestamps
  end
```

Now I want to change the type of one field form `:integer` to `:binary`.
What's the correct way of writing the migration because using `add` is not working...?

```
def change do
    alter table(:editables) do
      add :title, :binary
      add :content, :binary

      timestamps
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to use [modify/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#modify/3) to change the type. `add/3` is only for adding new columns.

```
alter table(:editables) do
  modify :content, :binary
end
```

Comment: but now i'm getting this error: `ERROR (datatype_mismatch): column "title" cannot be cast automatically to type bytea`

Comment: @PauloJaneiro If you can delete your database then deleting and recreating will fix it. The problem is that it won't be able to automatically migrate the type.

Comment: @PauloJaneiro be sure to update your schema in your model too.

Comment: Right. So this cannot be done when in production...Thanks Gazler.

Comment: One of your records will be causing the issue with incompatible data (maybe NULLs?) Check out http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAHyXU0xxCe8QUB3xNTS5aFKHLtigZCXQVu1KoXcm9_z86jp6qA@mail.gmail.com - it can be done but not with the Ecto migration DSL.

Comment: In my case I successfully migrated from :string to :text but I had to restart the server afterwards. I was getting a weird PostgreSQL error.