# Elixir: Modify table column in MYSQL with Ecto

Tags: mysql, ecto, elixir

I'm currently trying to write an `Ecto` migration in order to change a table column from a `VARCHAR(255)` type to `TEXT`. I had no luck so far, even though the migration runs "successfuly". I tried even raw SQL within the migration with:

```
def change do
  alter table(:my_table) do
    "alter table <my_table> modify <my_column> text"
  end
end
```

I also manually removed the migration from the `schema_migrations` table when changing the file to make sure it runs it again.

Any tips would be most welcomed.

Update.

Should read documentation better:

```
def change do
  alter table(:my_table) do
    modify :my_column, :text
  end
end
```

It's been answered elsewhere too, see [Gazler's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583625/how-to-change-field-type-in-ecto).